# How can I figure out the difference in seconds between two dates in IronPython?

Tags: ironpython

I have two datetime vars and need to figure out the difference between them in seconds.  since I can't use `datetime.strptime` like in Python, what should I use?

```
day1=('2016-10-28 08:11:36')
day2=('2016-10-28 10:32:45')
```

Answer (score 0):

So I *totally* stole this from [Sean Riley](https://community.tibco.com/questions/how-can-i-get-string-converted-datetime-without-using-strptime) in the Tibco Community forums but if he shows up I'll delete this and give him the points.

---

The problem comes in that Spotfire is using an old version of IronPython.  `strptime` is now located in the DateTime library whereas it was in the Time lib.  So this got me to where I wanted to be.

```
import datetime, time

day1=datetime.datetime.now()
day2=('2016-10-28 10:32:45')

day2=datetime.datetime(*time.strptime(day2, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")[:6])

print abs(day2-day1).seconds
```